# highchart datalabel Spacing Issue in line chart

Tags: highcharts

Here is my fiddle ,the value of 5000 & 3000 wil com **(5 000 & 3 000)** 'i want clear this' ..Plz

```
  <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/zxsfxzag/6/">My fiddle</a>
```

datalabel{
enable:true,
}

Comment: do you want clear all the values? or only 5000 and 3000

Comment: want 5000 not(5 000),,,Thx in advance

Comment: I think this is default. If value is 500, you can't get space but the value is 5000 then you get space. It's like [5,000][50,000]. comma separation gives you the space in highcharts

Comment: @user2573712 Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts has default thousands separator, you can find information about this separator here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#lang.thousandsSep

To avoid this space between thousands, simply set lang.thousandsSep to ''.

```
      Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
      thousandsSep: ''
    }
  });
```

Here you can see an example how it can work:
http://jsfiddle.net/m8uhsh3u/1/

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts has this default thousand separator applied to its label. Update `Highcharts.plotOptions.series.dataLabels.format` like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wiltsc/zxsfxzag/14/).